# Date conversion issue in JS

Tags: javascript, date, unix, momentjs, utc

I have a date in local time zone which is Mon Jan 13 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time).
I need this

> Jan 13 2020

date in UTC. when i converted using

```
moment(
    moment(start_date).format('mm-dd-yyyy'),
  ).Unix();
```

i am receiving a UNIX time stamp corresponding to the date Jan 12 2020 in UTC. 
what i need is for Jan 13 2020 get a UTC timestamp of date  Jan 13 2020 instead of getting Jan 12 2020. Time values are not important.

Comment: Unix timestamps are always in UTC time, so when you convert from any date at midnight, you would get the *previous date*. As long as you're in a timezone that has a positive offset to UTC.

Comment: If you have a string "Mon Jan 13 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" and just want to get "Jan 13 2020", then split the string and format it as you want (e.g. `dateString.substr(4, 11)`). Don't mess with Date objects and libraries if you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

Get the UTC timestamp like this:

```
moment.utc('Jan 13 2020').format('X')
```

Above will give you the UTC timestamp in seconds.

If you want milliseconds, use `x` instead of `X`.

Answer (score 0):

Breaking down your statement:

```
moment(start_date)
```

does not provide the parse format to moment.js so you will get a warning to that effect. In this case, moment.js will fallback to the built–in parser as if you'd written:

```
moment(Date.parse(start_date))
```

so you are hoping the built–in parser parses it correctly.

Then there is:

```
.format('mm-dd-yyyy')
```

which will return a date string in that format or Invalid Date if the parser couldn't parse the string.

However, likely you have used the wrong tokens so the result will be something like "30-mo-yyyy":

- mm is two digit minute, if you want two digit month then use MM
- dd is two letter day name, if you want two digit day in month use DD
- yyyy is not a valid token, if you want the four digit year then use YYYY

So the format tokens should be:

```
.format('MM-DD-YYYY')
```

The result is then passed to moment, again without specifying the input format so again moment will show a warning and use the built–in parser again with the same potential for errors or invalid Dates. If parsed correctly, it will return a Date for the local timezone for the Date.

```
.Unix()
```

Is not a valid moment method, likely you want `.unix()`, which produces a UNIX timestamp (time value) for the equivalent UTC time. If the host system is set to +5:30 then the UTC time will be 5:30 earlier (and if it's before 5:30 am local, the date will be the day before).

If you want to parse the string correctly and get a date for the start of the day, then do:

```
moment(start_date, 'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ').startOf('day').unix()
```

Or create a formatted string however you like. A much more common format is YYYY-MM-DD, so consider:

```js
let start_date = 'Mon Jan 13 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)';

// Get UNIX timestamp for start of day
console.log(
  moment(start_date, 'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ').startOf('day').unix()
);

// Get formatted date string
console.log(
  moment(start_date, 'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
);
console.log(
  moment(start_date, 'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ').format('DD MMM YYYY')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```